# Parse SQL canonical date with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

In my product dates are stores as a canonical SQL date in the database. `2011-10-24 00:00:00.000`

My application default date culture changes from customer to customer and
I like to parse the dates. How should I do that?

I currently use `(System.DateTime)"2011-10-24 00:00:00.000"` and on most machine this will work fine, I know that some machines get `InvalidCastException`

I really want to use `DateTime.ParseExact` and pass the [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) as an argument but i can't find it in the format list.

```
System.DateTime.ParseExact("2011-10-24 00:00:00.000", "<The format string>");
```

Edit:

Full code

```
DataTable table= GetDataTable();
Datetime date = (System.DateTime)table["DateCulomnName"];// Here is where the exception may be thrown
```

Comment: SQL `DateTime` does not have a "format". That's just how its displaying it to you. Are you really storing it as text?

Comment: You should store the dates as DATE / datetime /datetime2, not as strings

Comment: You're looking for the [Custom Date and Time Format list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) - but you shouldn't have to parse DateTime values retrieved from your database.

Comment: What is the datatype in your database for the date?

Comment: For this format `DateTime.Parse("2011-10-24 00:00:00.000")` should also works

Comment: @sepupic Changing the database is too much right now. Can you recommend another solution?

Comment: There *is* no other (sensible) solution. Don't store dates as text!

Comment: @Dolev you know your dates as string are useless if you even have 1 user in another timezone. You dates will mean nothing as they are not real.

Comment: Sorry about the last comment. The database stores them as datetime!

Comment: Then you dont need to "parse" anything. Your query will load them into .NET as `DateTime` automatically. Now im confused what your question actually is

Comment: Please add the code, where you fetch the data from DB.

Comment: @Jamiec , Well I get the invalid cast exception when the culture is French. Can you explain that?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - you can force a culture using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`

Comment: @Jamiec , I did. (System.DateTime)"2011-10-24 00:00:00.000" is where i get the error.

Comment: [`Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: @Dolev "Well I get the invalid cast exception when the culture is French" - in France everything is a little different ;) Please just add the code, where you are doing that, so we can analyze what's actually happening instead of guessing.

Comment: I call shenanigans -you cant cast a string to a datetime in *any* culture! http://rextester.com/CKVUV61475

Comment: formatstring would have to be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff" - but as has been said before: You shouldn't need it.

Comment: Add a new column to the table called tempdatetime, select the varchar datetime column into tempdatetime using convert. When done, drop the varchar datetime column and rename column tempdatetime to the original column name. Problem solved at source.

Comment: Are you sure your `DateCulomnName` field is not `null`? Try debugging and seeing *exactly* what the value of `table["DateCulomnName"]` is when that error occurs (And what datatype the compiler thinks the value is)

Comment: @Hans Remember OP is dealing with an already published product. It is not *that* easy ...

Comment: @Jamiec No. But the code is used intensively and the error reproduce only in the French culture

Comment: So debug and see the value causing the invalid cast. This is not something we can do for you.

Answer (score 3):

If the DB already has the column as DateTime, then it is unnecessary to convert it to a string, in order to get it into a DateTime variable.

Assignment from DateTime into a DataRow field can be done directly. Other way around, from DataRow field into a DateTime, you need a typecast. Like this:

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();
t.Columns.Add("DATE", typeof(DateTime));

DataRow r = t.NewRow();
r["DATE"] = DateTime.Now;

DateTime fromRow = (DateTime)r["DATE"];
```

This works just fine, regardless of CurrentCulture.

Having DateTime as string, should only be used when you actually want to present it in a UI or a log file.